# How to round the table view cells in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i want to round table-list cells either bottom or top side but not both sides can anybody please help me with example code and i have done like below but it round the both side edges but i want round only one side according to requirement(either top or bottom)

```
 [cell.layer setCornerRadius:7.0f];
  [cell.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
  [cell.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
```

This above code rounds both sides cells edges but i want round at one side edge please help me somebody

Comment: u can t do this, create the one UIView and add the above functions

Comment: please give me example code

Comment: r u use the custom cell class

Comment: i am here just using header for each sections when ever user click on this header cells are expanding so that i want round header view up-side corner and cell bottom side corner please help me with sample exampl

Comment: You can't round just some of the corners of a view by setting a layer's cornerRadius property. You can get the same effect using a bezier path, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually create a semi-circle shaped `UIView` or UITableViewCell like that unless you jump into core graphics yourself.

A simple hack that I would recommend is to have a `UIView` in the cell, with all the components insides the `UIView`. Now make that `UIView` into a round shape, and give the `UIView` a double height of the cell itself. So if your cell is of height 44, make the `UIView` with a height of 88. This way half of the `UIView` will get clipped because it won't be able to show in the cell itself.

And you will end up with a half part of a circle visible in a `UITableViewCell`.

Hope this helps you out. Please let me know if you have any trouble with it.

**Update:**

To achieve this, you can use a code similar to the following one:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.contentView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,(cell.frame.size.height*2.0),(cell.frame.size.height*2.0))];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [view.layer setCornerRadius:view.frame.size.height/2];
    [view setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [cell addSubview:view];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: danialzahid94 i am asking how can we round table list cells only at bottom side and top side we should not round we just leave that side like plane and  i am not expecting round view adding on cell

Comment: I don't think you can make the cell itself into a semi-circle. This is your best bet. And if you make the backgroundColor of the cell clearColor, the UIView will look just like a semi-circle cell.
And if you want to make the bottom side round for that view, you can use this line instead of the one in the answer:
`UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,(cell.frame.size.height*-1),(cell.frame.size.height*2.0),(cell.frame.size.height*2.0))];`

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieve through make image with top side round corner. set that image as a background image and set cell-background color as a clear color

Comment: cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"roundedCornerImage.PNG"]];

Answer (score 0):

in your Code apply this Code , i have tested , its working perfectly.

```
maskPath1 = (UIImageView *)[self roundCornersOnView: maskPath1 onTopLeft:YES topRight:YES bottomLeft:NO bottomRight:NO radius:20.0];
```

//use below Method to Set Corner Radius Round..

```
-(UIView *)roundCornersOnView:(UIView *)view onTopLeft:(BOOL)tl topRight:(BOOL)tr bottomLeft:(BOOL)bl bottomRight:(BOOL)br radius:(float)radius {

    if (tl || tr || bl || br) {
        UIRectCorner corner = 0; //holds the corner
        //Determine which corner(s) should be changed
        if (tl) {
            corner = corner | UIRectCornerTopLeft;
        }
        if (tr) {
            corner = corner | UIRectCornerTopRight;
        }
        if (bl) {
            corner = corner | UIRectCornerBottomLeft;
        }
        if (br) {
            corner = corner | UIRectCornerBottomRight;
        }

        UIView *roundedView = view;
        UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:roundedView.bounds byRoundingCorners:corner cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        maskLayer.frame = roundedView.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        roundedView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
        return roundedView;
    } else {
        return view;
    }

}
```

///////////// For TableVIew Use Below Code in cellForRowAtIndexPath Method /////

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.Img_thumb=(UIImageView *)[self roundCornersOnView: cell.Img_thumb onTopLeft:YES topRight:YES bottomLeft:NO bottomRight:NO radius:20.0];
}
```

Check Screen Shot :-> [image: Check Screen Shot you can see Round Corners]